# Vue How to implement webpack and service-workers

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

currently, my vue app has a package.json like this:

```js
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

In my `main.js` I have this:

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development')
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
else
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.net/api'
```

I would now like to use webpack to build my app and manage certain things.
What is the best way to integrate webpack into my project now and optimize it?
I would like to use a service-worker to inform the users about a new version every time and ask them to reload the page.

Comment: Please give more context, I really don't understand your needs here. A detailed description, and what you have tried so far, if you did, or some preliminary research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to *integrate* Webpack into a Vue CLI scaffolded project. Vue CLI [uses Webpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack) under the hood.

To configure the underlying Webpack, create `vue.config.js` with a [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack) or [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) property:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    //...
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    //...
  }
}
```

Regarding the Service Worker, you could use the [`@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` plugin](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html), which can be added to a Vue CLI project with this command:

```sh
$ vue add pwa
```